# C++0x "standard layout"

Tags: c++11

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data) a requirement for "standard-layout" is:

- Has the same access control (public, private, protected) for all non-static members

Does not that preclude objects with public methods and private data from ever being standard-layout?  What is the rationale for such a draconian rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does not that preclude objects with public methods and private data from ever being standard-layout?

No, the Wikipedia article <strike>has</strike> had the wrong wording. Only different access control for *data members* is mentioned in *§9/6* of the [FCD](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf), which treats standard-layout:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>   [...]
>   — has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static **data members**,

Comment: Georg, Your final quote includes the text "non-static _data_ members". My interest is in very simple classes in which _all_ _data members are private and some number of _function_ members / methods are public.  My question is why should not such an object be treated as "standard layout"?

Comment: @John: Sorry, i completely over-read that you talked about mixed access control for methods and data. Don't know how i missed that.